# Arduino : LCD / POT

Tags: programming

how can I make the repetitions stop at 10 ? Also how can I get the lcd to reset when its off/low ?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,5,4,3,2); 
const int tiltSensor = 8;
int reps = 0;
int switchState = HIGH;
int prevSwitchState = LOW;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16,2); // type of lcd(16 columns and 2 rows) 
  pinMode(tiltSensor,INPUT);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0); // the cursor is where on the 
  lcd the characters will be placed
  lcd.print("Workout Time"); // print is the characters on the screen 
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Lets GO ! ");
}

void loop() {
  switchState = digitalRead(tiltSensor);
  if (switchState != prevSwitchState) {
    if (switchState == LOW) {
      reps = reps + 1;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Reps:");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print(reps/10);
    }
  }
  prevSwitchState = switchState;
}
```

Comment: ... how can I get the lcd to reset when the potentiometer is turned off /low ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and not as an image. It is important that your question incl. the code can be proplery indexed for search. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: `if (reps < 10)`?

Comment: Learn to program.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I make the repetitions stop at 10 ?

use a loop counter:

```
  if (loop_cnt++ < 10) do_mything();
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to elaborate as to where in the loop its to be placed ? as I am new to this...